# Symfony: listener priority in bundle

Tags: symfony, listener

I have a REST API built with the framework Symfony 3.4 (and FOS Rest Bundle). I use the authentication with API keys to authenticate users (https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/security/api_key_authentication.html).
I installed the LexikMaintenanceBundle (https://github.com/lexik/LexikMaintenanceBundle) in order to add a maintenance mode to the API.

The issue is the authentication is always done in first, instead of checking first if the maintenance mode is enabled. Normally, the checking of maintenance mode should be done first before the authentication.

How can I change the priority of the listener created in a bundle? Or maybe there is another solution to change it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can control the order in which listeners are executed using the additional tag attribute `priority`. See the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/event_dispatcher.html#creating-an-event-listener). The higher the number the earlier a listener is executed, default is 0.

You can give the `MaintenanceListener` a higher priority (any positive value, e.g. 10) by adding the `priority` attribute in `LexikMaintenanceBundle/Resources/config/services.xml`:

`<tag name="kernel.event_listener" event="kernel.request" method="onKernelRequest" priority="10" />`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But you propose to change the priority directly inside the bundle, but it's not a good way to do. Nothing must be changed directly from a bundle.

Comment: Then you can override the default configuration of the bundle by defining a prepended configuration as described [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/prepend_extension.html).

Comment: Can you just be more explicit? Example of code? Thanks a lot

Comment: Pawel you suggest overriding directly the services.xml file inside the bundle and then overriding the default configuration with a prepend configuration?